# Can i get physical address of a variable or object in C#?

Tags: c#

I am supposed to do a project in C# to present how a list does work.

I'm thinking it's a good idea to show in a graphic interface like this:

-in "value" field: value of node
-in "next" field: physical address of next node

Is this possible?

Comment: Your `List` implementation can contain *high level* memory management as well, if your intent is to demonstrate how memory is used.

Comment: unless the variable is `fixed` there is no guarantee it won't change location.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: It's worth noting that managed variables can generally be moved around during a garbage collection, as the garbage collector can (and will) defragment memory

Comment: Note that you can't get a physical address. All what you can get is virtual address

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zcbcf4ta%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Jodrell note that stack variables (locals) won't move around; instance variables (fields) can though, yes

Comment: Dan, did my answer help you? If not, please tell me, otherwise, it would be awesome if you can accept it as the answer to your question =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with unsafe code (at least the virtual address, not the raw *physical* memory address, but that's just what you want).

Have a look at [MSDN: How to: Obtain the Address of a Variable (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-obtain-the-address-of-a-variable) for details. It guides you through compiling the following example (it requires unsafe code to be enabled in the project properties or the `/unsafe` switch) and what traps you could experience when getting the location of moveable variables, which require the `fixed` keyword to stay at the same location, basically said.

```
int number;
int* p = &number; //address-of operator &
```

Comment: This question is about C# so my answer is too ;) Indeed, unsafe C# code looks much like C/C++.

Comment: Oh unsafe keyword.. I just end up in surprise.